# Wrong link in comment title. Can I change it?

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, comments, facebook-comments

I have webshop and I added FB comments there. Everything works well but the page name link "USERNAME commented on PAGE NAME" is wrong. The url of commented product is http://www.domain.com/store/product_info.php?products_id=27 but the link shows it http://www.domain.com/?products_id=27.

Can I add the missing parts (store/product_info.php) to the link?

Answer (score 0):

You should correct that link on your end by using actual URL for your page within `href`/`data-href` attribute of [Comments social plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/)

**NOTES:** Comments plugin will work even if you'll use wrong URL for it (even non-existing URL may be used) and the comments will be linked with the URL used, if you change it you will loose all existing comments!

Comment: The link is correct, I checked it form source code. Still the link in FB shows its wrong (without store/?products_id=27).

Comment: Than check that your OpenGraph tags have correct one as well as comments plugin (until you provide a link to your page we can only guess what is the problem)

Comment: page is: http://www.triathlonhaaste.fi/store/product_info.php?cPath=5&products_id=27. Check this (http://i7.aijaa.com/b/00590/10325341.jpg) picture too. There is red circle around the link what is wrong.

Comment: @SammakkoSami, Looks like this related to some issue with parsing your page by OpenGraph Linter. OpenGraph tags are exists on page but [doesn't shown in debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=www.triathlonhaaste.fi%2Fstore%2Fproduct_info.php%3Fproducts_id%3D27). Probably broken links is some sort of schema that existed at some period of time and the details doesn't updated, since then... You may try to [file a bug on Facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/create) to see if it's the case...

Answer (score 0):

Check your URL with the [Facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) – that’ll tell you what page FB actually reads. Common mistakes are f.e. having a wrong canonical URL set or something smilar.

Comment: Debugger tells that everything is ok except og:image which is under 200px. Product name works well but the link after user name is wrong. You can test http://www.triathlonhaaste.fi/store/product_info.php?products_id=27

Comment: Works totally fine for me if I post that link directly on Facebook.

Comment: Sharing through the like button on your site I get http://aijaa.com/0042610325391 – both links, that in the message on top and that beside the picture, correctly link back to your article detail page.

Comment: I don't know why I have link where is missing folder and main page (store/product_info.php). This is weird.